# Push для односвязнного списка

Tags: c, указатели, структуры, список, push

Не могу разобраться в этой функции. Особенно интересно, почему используется двойной указатель для передачи элемента списка.

```
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) { 

struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

new_node->data  = new_data; 

new_node->next = (*head_ref); 

(*head_ref)    = new_node; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В С аргументы передаются в функцию по значению. То есть функции имеют дело с копиями значений своих аргументов.

Если вы хотите передать аргумент по ссылке, чтобы функция имела дело с самим исходным аргументом, а не с копией его значения, то вам следует передать указатель на аргумент, а внутри функции разыменовывать этот указатель.

Рассмотрите вашу функцию, но в которой передается не указатель на указатель на начало списка, а сам исходный указатель на начало списка.

```
void push( struct Node *head_ref, int new_data ) 
{ 
    struct Node *new_node = ( struct Node * )malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) ); 

    new_node->data  = new_data; 

    new_node->next = head_ref; 

    head_ref    = new_node; 
}
```

Тогда вызов этой функции можно представить следующим образом. Допустим есть объявление начала списка и для него вызывается данная функция. Тогда можно логически представить вызов следующим образом

```
struct Node *head = NULL;
push( head, 10 );

// И вот как можно представить работу функции
void push( struct Node *head_ref, int new_data ) 
{ 
    struct Node *head_ref = head;

    // ....

    head_ref    = new_node; 
}
```

То есть внутри функции меняется значение переменной `head_ref`. Значение исходной переменной `head` осталось неизменным.

Именно поэтому `head` следует передавать по ссылке то есть через указатель на него

```
void push( struct Node **head_ref, int new_data ) 
{ 
    struct Node **head_ref = &head;

    // ....

    *head_ref    = new_node; 
}
```

В этом случае будет изменено значение исходной переменной `head`.

Рассмотрите также следующую демонстрационную программу.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( char *p )
{
    p = "Bye";
}

void g( char **p )
{
    *p = "Bye";
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "Hello";

    printf( "Before f( s ) s = %s\n", s );
    f( s );
    printf( "After  f( s ) s = %s\n", s );

    printf( "\nBefore g( s ) s = %s\n", s );
    g( &s );
    printf( "After  g( s ) s = %s\n", s );

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
Before f( s ) s = Hello
After  f( s ) s = Hello

Before g( s ) s = Hello
After  g( s ) s = Bye
```

Так как функция `f` имеет дело с копией значения указателя `s`, то она меняет именно эту копию, которая помещается в ее параметр `p`. Сама переменная `s` не изменяется.

Функция `g` имеет дело с указателем на переменную `s`, а потому, разыменовывая этот указатель, функция имеет доступ к самой переменной `s` и меняет ее значение.

Answer (score 1):

```
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) 
{ 
    // Выделили память для нового узла
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
    // Записали туда данные
    new_node->data  = new_data; 
    // Он теперь указывает туда, куда указывала голова списка
    new_node->next = (*head_ref); 
    // А голова теперь указывает на новый узел...
    (*head_ref)    = new_node; 
}
```

А если вы передадите одинарный указатель, типа

```
void push(struct Node* head_ref, int new_data) 
{ 
    ...
    head_ref    = new_node; 
}
```

то в функцию будет передана *копия* головы, и после

```
struct Node head;
...
push(head,0);
```

значение в `head` останется неизменным. В отличие от случая двойного указателя:

```
struct Node head;
...
push(&head,0);
```

Здесь значение `head` после вызова изменится...